# Google Analytics for Mobile Apps iOS SDK v3 event tracking

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm using [Google Analytics for Mobile Apps iOS SDK v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/). Screen tracking is working fine, but I cant get event tracking to work. Xcode shows error:

```
No known class method for selector 'createEventWithCategory:withAction:withLabel:withValue:'
```

My code is:

```
- (IBAction)callButton:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12345"]];
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];    
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"
                                                  withAction:@"button_press"
                                                   withLabel:@"play_button"
                                                   withValue:nil] build]];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"ui_action"
                                                      action:@"button_press"
                                                       label:@"play_button"
                                                       value:nil] build]];
```